# Calculating canvas 3D coordinates

Tags: html, canvas, transform, skew

I have made slight variation on a 3D bar chart:

**Original:**

[image]

**Updated:**

[image]

The change was done by skewing the canvas with transform() and then drawing the chart.

Now, after the canvas is skewed the coordinates that are recorded for each bar are no longer correct. How would I alter them in order to account for the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: the skew value that you give to the transform() function is the tangent of the angle (in radians) by which the chart is skewed. So with that you can adjust the coordinates appropriately. For example:

http://www.rgraph.net/